# How to apply Infinite scroll effect using 'react-infinite-scroll-component' into local JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, infinite-scroll

I am testing frontEnd, so I have installed **'react-infinite-scroll-component'** as a dependency. I want to **apply the effect to the local Json data**, and **don't want to make any API call** for the time being.
I am stuck as How should I achieve this?
Here's what I have done so far

*My Json Data*

```
[{ "id" : 1, "name" : "bob"}, //inside public folder
{ "id" : 2, "name" : "sam"},
{ "id" : 3, "name" : "drake"},
{ "id" : 4, "name" : "catherine"},
{ "id" : 5, "name" : "terry"},
{ "id" : 6, "name" : "simon"},
{ "id" : 7, "name" : "max"},
{ "id" : 8, "name" : "steve"},
{ "id" : 9, "name" : "adam"},
{ "id" : 10, "name" : "stella"},
{ "id" : 11, "name" : "jacob"},
... //and so on
]
```

I am consuming this Json data into my component as (using .ts)

```
import myData from 'path-where-this-data-reside-into-my-project-directory';
**// I could console.log to check if data is imported or not, so it is working fine till this point**

    export default function MyComponent () {
    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.get('./DummyData') // this Dummydata resides into my public folder
    .then (response => setData([...data, response.data])
    .then(console.log(data));
    }}
    
    return (
    <InfiniteScroll
    hasMore = {true}
    loader = {<MyLoadingComponent />}
    dataLength = {data.length}
    next = {fetchData}
    endMessage = {<p>ALl Set!</p>}
    >
    {data.map((x) => (
     <Typography key = {x.id}>{x.name}</Typography>
    ))}
    </InfiniteScroll>
    );
```

I want to apply this infinite scroll effect to the local json data, for the time being only. How could I achieve this functionality !
I want to set up the page size and page number, so as to display only few objects from my Json array at a time (as 3 objects at a time).
since axios.get('') expects string Url, how could I fetch the local json data, with the page number included and pageSize so as to see only a fraction of it and not the entire data into one go.

All Suggestions would be highly respected : )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would normally make this "3 objects at a time"-query through your API-call, but cannot do that with your locally fetched data (?).
In that case, to test locally, cant you just slice your data array after fetching it? Something like this:
(EDITED):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {

    // Store the local data in this state separately, because you do not fetch 3 rows at a time from local file
    const [localData, setLocalData] = useState([])

    // this is the actual data that will be displayed, so we will update this state when adding three additional rows from the local data
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    // this is simply a constant representing the amount of items that will be added to the display data from the local data each time
    const itemsPerPage = 3


    // I use useEffect here to load the local data when the component mounts.
    useEffect(() => {
        // fetch the local data
        fetchData()
        // then update the display data with the first three entries
        updateDataFromLocalData()
    }, [])


    // fetches the local data ONCE when called in the useEffect!
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('./DummyData') // this Dummydata resides into my public folder
        setLocalData([...response.data])
    }

    // this is the function we use to update the display data from your previously fetched local data
    const updateDataFromLocalData = () => {
        setData([...data, localData.slice(data.length, data.length + itemsPerPage)])
    }

    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<MyLoadingComponent />}
            dataLength={data.length}
            next={updateDataFromLocalData}
            endMessage={<p>ALl Set!</p>}
        >
            {data.map((x) => (
                <Typography key={x.id}>{x.name}</Typography>
            ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
    )
}
```

Comment: Then how am I supposed to get the next batch of data? Please help!, on working with this code of yours, I am able to get 1st two entries, I want to fetch all entries using infinite scroll effect (which is essientially provided by <InfiniteScroll /> component. ). When the response is returned, I want to keep on adding next two items when it reaches the bottom of the page, just like the infinite scroll effect

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide a more elaborate code example. I haven't actually tested that code tho, so you might have to debug some parts. The basic idea is to fetch your localData once, keep it in state, then append more lines to your actual display data from it whenever you reach the bottom of your infinite scroll. Potentially not the optimal approach, since it requires preloading the entire dataset, but since you wont do that in production (by querying for three rows at a time from your data API) it isn't an issue for testing. Hope this helps.

Comment: A little correction is needed. Use spread operator (...) with localData to avoid appending new array as sub array.

setData([...data, ...localData.slice(data.length, data.length + itemsPerPage)])